# Animal Husbandry

Tags: discussion

We occasionally get questions about animals who are not pets, Some we point to [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) but according to this Area51 post [Animal husbandry is on-topic on Sustainability.SX](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19310) we might also consider sending some of them towards [Sustainability](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would see no reason not to if we can determine that the question is related to sustainable living and not general breeding or commercial farming.